# Is there a module/solution for allowing users to block each other on an SNS site?

Tags: users

Is there a module or solution that allows users to block each other on a social networking site?  For example, if a user blocks another they will no longer see that user's profile or any content posted by that user.

I imagine one could do something like this with the flag module, but it seems like it might get extraordinarily complicated...

Comment: By the way, I'm on Drupal 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [Ignore User](http://drupal.org/project/ignore_user) module.  From the project page:

> This module allows a user to "ignore" content from other users that
>   they do not wish to view. Node and comment content from an ignored
>   user is hidden from view on a page. A message is displayed above the
>   hidden block of content with a link to the user's "ignore list" and a
>   link to toggle display of the ignored user's block of content in that
>   node or comment.

Not sure if it will handle blocking a profile view or not, but it should block content.

Comment: Thanks, but I forget to mention I'm on Drupal 7.  I've updated the question.

Comment: There is a version in dev for D7, not sure how functional it is yet, could always give it a try.  Otherwise you would probably have to write a module yourself