# Ignore Users Content with Flags>

Tags: views, users, rules, flags

I am developing a network of websites for our nonprofit organization.

As with any membership site, we have some members who simply do not get along and often, their back and forth "drama" will detract from the other member's positive, supportive experiences.

Rather than simply banning members who can't get along with each other, we'd like to set up a way for members to flag a member and "mute" them, so that instead of seeing their content, they will see a message like "You have muted this member and cannot view their post. To unmute the member, visit your profile page." or something to that effect.

There was a module for 6 that is  ported to 7 called Ignore User, but it doesn't seem to be in a stable release for 7.

It seems to me that there has to be some way to do this with flags, rules, and views -- but I admit it is a bit above my knowledge level.

Has anyone ever done something like this on a Drupal 7 site? Can you help me make this work? I really do feel it will make a big difference for our chapters and minimize some of the "drama" we have to deal with on a regular basis.

Thanks
Heather

Comment: Do you mean comments and/or nodes with 'content'? How do you display them on your website now?

Comment: Mostly through views and panels: my group pages are made up of panels and views, as are my forums - the only content that doesn't go through a panel right now is just the basic article (which, honestly would be okay to leave alone as only certain roles can post it). 

I am more interested in filtering out forum topics and my custom group forum topic content type, which is where the majority of the back and forth happens.

Is there a way to put a contextual filter on a view or panel that rewrites the body field to be the 'blocked content' message for users that the user viewing has flagged?

Comment: Which fields from the node do you display in your view? Only the title?

Comment: Well in the forum topic view, they will see the node title and body, then the comment titles and bodies.

I want it to replace the body of the node or comment (so whether it is a "new topic" or a "reply") with the "muted user" message if you have flagged that user as muted.

Comment: This is something that is available in phpbb3, if it helps to have an example of how it works. It is called the "foe" feature on their software.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/23426/is-there-a-module-solution-for-allowing-users-to-block-each-other-on-an-sns-site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [Ignore User](https://drupal.org/project/ignore_user), but for D7 there is only a dev version that hasn't seen any progress in over 2 years. Might be worth a look though, maybe you can start with that and even contribute back any improvements.

Everything else would require a considerable amount of configuration concerning the flags themselves, any views listings and node displays. Probably you will even need to do some custom coding.

Comment: It won't let me upvote you yet, but thank you for helping me!

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) I'm glad I could help. You should be able to accept this answer (a green icon somewhere) ;) if it was helpful.